# The convergence of the series $\sum\limits_{n=3}^\infty \frac {1} {n^2\ln(\ln(n))}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is the series $$\sum\limits_{n=3}^\infty \frac {1} {n^2\ln(\ln(n))}$$ convergent?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to MSE. To help you, it's useful to know what you already tried

Answer (score 7):

It is convergent as it is positive and bounded above by $\sum 1/n^2$ which  is already convergent as can be proven using the [integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence).

Answer (score 4):

$$\bullet \text{ Cauchy condensation criterion:}$$
$$ \text{Let $a_n$ be a decreasing sequence of non-negative numbers, then}$$
$$\sum_n a_n <+\infty \iff\sum_n2^na_{2^n}<+\infty $$

$$\implies \sum_{n=3}^{+\infty}\cfrac{1}{n^2\log\log(n)}<+\infty \iff \sum_{n=3}^{+\infty}\cfrac{2^n}{(2^n)^2\log\log2^n}<+\infty$$

$$\text{so,}$$
$$\sum_{n=3}^{+\infty}\cfrac{2^n}{(2^n)^2\log\log2^n}=\sum_{n=3}^{+\infty}\cfrac{1}{(2^n)\log\big(n\log(2)\big)}\le\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\cfrac{1}{2^n}=\cfrac{1}{4}<+\infty$$

$$\text{Hence, }\quad \fbox{$\quad \sum_{n=3}^{+\infty}\cfrac{1}{n^2\log\log(n)}<+\infty$}$$